# python tag in rml for loop to insert empty rows

Tags: python, odoo, rml

I have a table in my report which look like.

```
A    B  C             
-------------\      
1    2  3                 
4    5  6     
--------------\
```

Now want to insert fixed number of empty rows at the end

```
A   B   C              
-------------\               
1   2   3            
4   5   6       
empty row        
empty row    
empty row     


-------------\
```

Please give some way to do this.

```
 <section>
      <para style="terp_default_8">[[repeatIn(o.order_line,'line')]][["" for l in range(10), 'line']]</para>
      <blockTable colWidths="20.0,100.0,150.0,80.0,50.0,20.0,60.0,50.0" style="Table_Order_Pur_line_Content">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <para style="terp_default_9"> </para>
          </td>
          <td>
            <para style="terp_default_9">[[ ', '.join(map(lambda x: x.name, line.taxes_id)) ]]</para>
          </td>
          <td>
            <para style="terp_default_9">[[line.name]]</para>
          </td>
          <td>
            <para style="terp_default_Right_9">[[ formatLang(line.product_qty ) ]]</para>
          </td>
          <td>
            <para style="terp_default_Right_9">[[ formatLang(line.price_unit,digits=get_digits(dp='Product Price') ) ]]</para>
          </td>
          <td>
            <para style="terp_default_Right_9"> </para>
          </td>
     <td>
            <para style="terp_default_Right_9"> </para>
          </td>
     <td>
            <para style="terp_default_Right_9">[[ formatLang(line.price_subtotal,digits=get_digits(dp='Account'), currency_obj=o.pricelist_id.currency_id ) ]] </para>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </blockTable>
    </section>
```

Comment: I fear that this question will be closed soon, unless you show what you have tried so far.

Comment: If you will print your code it will be possible to help you...

Comment: `<section><para style="terp_default_8"> [[repeatIn(o.order_line,'line')]][["" for l in range(10), 'line']]</para>    <blockTablecolWidths="20.0,100.0,150.0,80.0,50.0,20.0,60.0,50.0" style="Table_Order_Pur_line_Content">
  <tr>
          <td>
            <para style="terp_default_9"> </para>
          </td>
</tr>
</blockTable></section>`

Comment: You may want to look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226100/how-to-add-dynamic-empty-rows-in-table-with-rml-code

Comment: That is also posted by me But couldn't found answer yet.