# OpenERP RML report with the fixed size table

Tags: python, odoo, rml

I have used default python tag for repeatRows and repatln.
But I want to add empty rows at the bottom to make my table big.
this is the code.

```
  <para style="terp_default_8">[[repeatIn(o.order_line,'line')]][["" for l in range(10), 'line']]</para>
  <blockTable colWidths="20.0,100.0,150.0,80.0,50.0,20.0,60.0,50.0" style="Table_Order_Pur_line_Content">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <para style="terp_default_9"> </para>
      </td>
      <td>
        <para style="terp_default_9">[[ ', '.join(map(lambda x: x.name, line.taxes_id)) ]]</para>
      </td>
      <td>
        <para style="terp_default_9">[[line.name]]</para>
      </td>
      <td>
        <para style="terp_default_Right_9">[[ formatLang(line.product_qty ) ]]</para>
      </td>
      <td>
        <para style="terp_default_Right_9">[[ formatLang(line.price_unit,digits=get_digits(dp='Product Price') ) ]]</para>
      </td>
      <td>
        <para style="terp_default_Right_9"> </para>
      </td>
 <td>
        <para style="terp_default_Right_9"> </para>
      </td>
 <td>
        <para style="terp_default_Right_9">[[ formatLang(line.price_subtotal,digits=get_digits(dp='Account'), currency_obj=o.pricelist_id.currency_id ) ]] </para>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </blockTable>
</section>##
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [python tag in rml for loop to insert empty rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933111/python-tag-in-rml-for-loop-to-insert-empty-rows)

Comment: In that way i get the multiple same entry not the blank rows.