# how to add dynamic empty rows in table with RML code?

Tags: report, odoo, rml, purchase-order

How can i add empty blank rows in purchase report? and dont know if blank_line is executing perfectly. i followed this link [Openerp purchase report][1]  [1]: http://forum.openerp.com/forum/topic8508.html
code:

```
   <section>
  <para style="terp_default_8">[[ repeatIn(o.order_line,'line') ]][[line_no() ]]</para>
    <blockTable colWidths="20.0,100.0,150.0,80.0,50.0,20.0,60.0,50.0" style="Table_Order_Pur_line_Content">
      <tr>[[ blank_line(10) ]]<!--[[ setTag('para','para') ]] -->
      <td>
            <para style="terp_default_9"> </para>
          </td>
          <td>
            <para style="terp_default_9">[[ ', '.join(map(lambda x: x.name, line.taxes_id)) ]]</para>
          </td>
          <td>
            <para style="terp_default_9">[[line.name]]</para>
          </td>
          <td>
             <para style="terp_default_Right_9">[[ formatLang(line.product_qty ) ]]</para>
           </td>
          <td>
            <para style="terp_default_Right_9">[[ formatLang(line.price_unit,digits=get_digits(dp='Product Price') ) ]]</para>
           </td>
             <td>
                <para style="terp_default_Right_9"> </para>
              </td>
         <td>
                <para style="terp_default_Right_9"> </para>
              </td>
         <td>
                    <para style="terp_default_Right_9">[[ formatLang(line.price_subtotal,digits=get_digits(dp='Account'), currency_obj=o.pricelist_id.currency_id ) ]] </para>
            </td>
    </tr>
</blockTable>
```

[[repeatIn(o.order_line, 'o') ]]

```
    <blockTable colWidths="20.0,100.0,150.0,80.0,50.0,20.0,60.0,50.0" style="Table_Order_Pur_line_Content_blank">
    <tr> 
         <td> <para style="terp_default_8"><font color="white"> </font></para></td>
         <td> <para style="terp_default_8"><font color="white"> </font></para></td>
         <td> <para style="terp_default_8"><font color="white"> </font></para></td>
         <td> <para style="terp_default_8"><font color="white"> </font></para></td>
         <td> <para style="terp_default_8"><font color="white"> </font></para></td>
         <td> <para style="terp_default_8"><font color="white"> </font></para></td>
         <td> <para style="terp_default_8"><font color="white"> </font></para></td>
         <td> <para style="terp_default_8"><font color="white"> </font></para></td>
    </tr>
      </blockTable> -->
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your report code (let say order.py) create a method returning a list with the appropriate number of None elements :

```
def _empty_rows(self, n):
    return [ None for i in range(n) ]
```

Expose this method trough the *localcontext* dictionary in the *__init__* method like this:

```
def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context):
    ....
    self.localcontext.update( {
        'empty_rows': self._empty_rows,
        ....
    })
    ....
```

Use it in your RML file (order.rml for ex.) to create the desired number of rows:

```
   [[ repeateIn(empty_rows(10)) ]]
```

Comment: can you explain me what do you mean by Expose this method trough localcontext dictionary?? where should i write my whole empty row function?

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you modify the footer and add the total and other fields to footer? Then total will always come at the footer

Comment: But i want the lines till the end. So table looks bigger.

Comment: you can draw a line in rml

Comment: then there will be overlapped multiple lines.

Comment: [http://forum.openerp.com/forum/topic8508.html]  I want to do this way but answer is not working for me.